# global static table mismatch in the access code

Tags: c, compilation, linker

I have two .c files(X,y) which access a global table.

From X.c when I access the tables I get wrong values?
From Y.c when I access the tables I get the correct values?

Checked the base address of the table and offset in both locations. They remain 
the same.

This table is compiled separately and exported using extern. What I am missing out. The behavior looks strange.

The table should be accessed from both object files in the same way.

Comment: I got this issue because of the misalignment in the table. As the X.c was compiled with different compiler flags and y.c was compiled with different compiler flags. It is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I got this issue because of the misalignment in the table. As the X.c was compiled with different compiler flags and y.c was compiled with different compiler flags. It is fixed. – humblefool